# How to get the distinct list of grouped column and concatenating them in a column on Excel using any formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im looking for a way using Excel Formula only, to get the distinct list of column Transporation where it group by column Section then concatenating the result on column Transportation Mode. See my table for example.

```
ID  Student     Section  Transportation Transportation Mode
1   John        A        Walk           Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
2   Mary        A        Walk           Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
3   Amir        A        Commute        Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
4   Joseph      A        Car            Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
5   Kristern    A        Car            Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
6   Rose        A        Car            Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
7   Eric        A        Bike           Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
8   Ching Chong A        Bike           Walk + Commute + Car + Bike
9   Jet         B        Walk           Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
10  Mike        B        Car            Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
11  James       B        Bike           Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
12  Brandon     B        Bike           Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
13  Kenneth     B        Bike           Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
14  Mark        B        Teleport       Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
15  Julie       B        Motorcycle     Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
16  Pat         B        Motorcycle     Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
17  Vivian      B        Motorcycle     Walk + Car + Bike + Teleport + Motorcycle
18  Trish       C        Fly            Fly + Walk
19  Eli         C        Walk           Fly + Walk
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula then use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$20,$C$2:$C$20=C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @scott Craner! I love your answer. Too bad our excel doesnt have 'Unique formula' which is sad. But this gave me hope. Im looking for a way to change the 'Unique formula' with other alternatives.

Comment: If you do not have `UNIQUE()` most likely you do not have `TEXTJOIN()` either as there is only one version of excel that has the later but not the former.  If you do not have TEXTJOIN then most likely vba will be your only choice.